# Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.0 while importing visual studio project

Tags: advanced-installer

I tried to import a visual studio project made with C# for the trial application and I get an error message while importing the visual studio solution.

I am using VS 2019 Community and AdvancedInstaller 2020 R1.
Here is the list of packages for VS:

1. ASP.NET and web development
2. .NET desktop development
3. Desktop developing with C++
4. Visual Studio extension development
5. .NET Core cross-platform development

[Picture of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NASXF.png)

I saw people resolve the issue by adding bindings. But it didn't work for me. Here is my App.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe"
                                  publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                                  culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.4.1"
                                 newVersion="4.0.4.1"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I got the trial c# code from youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbDviXKCFS4
Please let me know what to do to resolve the error.